# Why do multimeters have an aluminium foil at the back?

Tags: ground, multimeter

I was wondering what is the purpose of aluminium foil at the back of some multimeters? I did a continuity test and found that it is connected to the ground (COM) terminal.

My initial guess was that it was some kind of shield but since it wasn't fully enclosed and multimeters don't work in that high RF range it didn't seem plausible. Also, it wasn't some kind of ground plane as it is only connected to the board at one point via the spring.

What is it exactly?

[image: Strange foil]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a shield, but to keep RF out, not in. The multimeter does not use high frequencies internally, but it does have high-impedance internal nodes that could be affected by external sources of RF.

Comment: alright,but would a thin sheet be any good ? High frequency radiation like those from cell phones can penetrate the shield easily .

Comment: Try it! Measure a resistance value with your phone on a call or on WiFi, with and without the shield and let us know how you get on.

Comment: @kishore yes radio waves will get in, but not by penetrating the shield. Even thin foil will almost completely stop electromagnetic waves above a MHz. But as it's not a cage, they'll just get in the sides. This shield is for 50 Hz fields though, and will work fairly well if grounded to the circuit, anywhere.

Answer (score 6):

Dave Tweed's answer has certainly got merit but my first thought is to prevent "hand" effects altering readings. Clearly, if the DMM is sat on a wooden bench or maybe sat upright on it's stand it will produce the same reading but, if you are cupping it in your hand, all that extra capacitance could affect AC measurements given that some of the circuit nodes are (as Dave says) very high impedance.

The same argument for sitting the DMM on a conductive bench. Similar sort of argument for stopping some digital areas/signals coupling to some sensitive measurement areas via external capacitance such as hand or a metal bench.

I'm putting forward that there are significant reasons for using an "earthed" shield to keep measurement repeatability good.

Comment: This is what I've always known the shield to be for.

Answer (score 5):

It's a partial Faraday cage to shield internal high impedance nodes against coupling. In operation, the PCB of the meter may be a high voltage, perhaps AC, with respect to surrounding conductive objects (a metal bench, a wire, your hand). That will cause increased noise on a dual slope A/D converter, and will cause a reading error when rectified by the AC-DC converter circuit used for AC volts and AC current.

When I designed a line of DC panel meters we did not find a shield necessary but for AC current meters (50mV full scale) a shield within the metal enclosure was necessary with the shield connected to the 'ground' of the circuit and the metal case earthed.

Answer (score 0):

As said below, its indeed a partial faraday cage, it is necessary to protect high impedance nodes from rf, also however it protects sensible ICs namely in this case the ADC, which can be affected by EMI regardless of the input and supply configuration